# How to detect when user start download in browser?

Tags: c#

I have searched extensively and have not found a solution.

Here is what im looking for:

When a user starts a download in a browser, I wish to move it to the download manager and remove the dialog download from browser, is this possible in C#?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this functionality? Browsers already have this built in so, i'm just wondering why you are re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

It is fundamentally impossible for server-side code to modify the browser's download experience.

Comment: +1, C# on the server surely won't, but it may be worth mentioning the OP could add an ActiveX plugin to the page which might-could.

Comment: But they're using client-side, I guess. (Free Download Manager, etc)

Comment: what do you mean `you guess`? Free Download Manager isn't a Web Browser, sounds like a chameleon question.. @sixlettervariable an ActiveX control - oh lord, it would neeed a 7% disclaimer: http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/06/kogan-imposing-tax-on-shoppers-who-use-ie7/